# Error when you edit the connection properties in SSAS

Tags: ssas

When I want to edit connection properties on SSAS for some tabular database (Impersonalisation Info: ImpersonateServiceAccount) when I click OK I got following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SString, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken='numberhere'' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I don't now what is the problem. I tried to google but I didn't find anything about this error. From my solution in VS I can deploy tabular model but it seems that data are not processed.

[-----------------IMAGE OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usZNX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I updated my SSMS to latest version and now everything is OK.